# Search in Azure Data Catalog key insensitive

Tags: azure, azure-data-catalog

I'm trying to figure out how to search by filename in data catalog, without being key insensitive.

g.e.:

- I have 3 files: "filename.csv", "FILENAME.csv", "fileName.csv"
- I want to get just the file "filename.csv" (in lower case).
- If I search with the name:

[image]

- I am getting back the 3 files (with double quotes and without, it returns the same).

Is there any way to get back just the file in lower case? Or how can avoid the key insensitive problem?

Thanks in advance.

Cheers,
Jon

Comment: How about using `:` instead of `=`? like: `name:"filename.csv"`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datacatalog/data-catalog-search-syntax-reference#property-scoped-searches

Comment: Thanks for the response Leo. Doing that doesn't solve the key insensitive issue, and also would include for example files called "1_filename.csv". So I guess I should use `=` instead of `:`

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datacatalog/data-catalog-search-syntax-reference explains how things work. But the short version is that the search is case insensitive and there isn't a way to avoid that.